# Eclipse, CheckboxTreeViewer, Select certain element (and scroll view)

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I'm struggling with the following problem. I've to rework some existing code (which for some reasons I cannot show) on the following problem.
It's using a Eclipse *CheckboxTreeViewer* to display some datatree:

```
Root
 - Level 1
   - Level 1.1
   - Level 1.2
 - Level 2
   - Level 2.1
   - Level 2.2
 - Level 3
   - Level 3.1
   - Level 3.2
   - Level 3.3
   - Level 3.4
   - Level 3.5
```

The whole tree ist displayed in some kind of ScrollPane. If I check now a CheckBox in the lower part (e.g. *3.5*) the whole "view" is scrolled up to *Root*. But it should stay at the last changed CheckBox (i.e. *3.5*).

I tried (among other things) something like:

```
ISelection selection = myCheckboxTreeViewer.getSelection();
updateCheckboxTreeViewer(); //within this method the nested CheckBoxes are set
myCheckboxTreeViewer.setSelection(selection);
```

Well, that doesn't work. In fact the "view" isn't reset to "Root" but somewhere in the middle.

As I'm not very firm on using Eclipse "stuff" has any one some idea where to start / go on / look further?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: CheckboxTreeViewer doesn't usually do any scrolling on its own. So you need to tell us more about 'some kind of scroll pane'. Show us an [mcve] (which doesn't have to be your actual code but must demonstrate the problem).

Comment: That's easily said. It's an undocumented mess of more than 3400 lines of codes... Well, I'll try my best.

Comment: @Simon We understand that it's not easy to isolate the issue and come up with an MCVE, but imagine how hard it is for people who can't even see the code to give you suggestions as to what might be wrong.